# Keras loss seems to be wrong - weighted sum is wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras with tensorflow backend to train a model with multiple outputs but only one loss (MSE on output layer "parts"). This is defined as follows:

```
model = Model(inputs=[image, year], outputs=outputs) # outputs is a list of 8 output layers
model_parallel = keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2, cpu_merge=True, cpu_relocation=False)
losses = {'parts': keras.losses.mean_squared_error}
loss_weights = {'parts': 1.}
model_parallel.compile(loss=losses,
                       loss_weights=loss_weights,
                       optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=args.lr)
                       )
model_parallel.fit_generator(generator=generator_training,
                             epochs=args.epochs,
                             verbose=1
                             )
```

fit_generator prints the total loss and my parts_loss:

```
33/5730 [..............................] - ETA: 14:28:59 - loss: 117.6318 - parts_loss: 97.1686
```

Why is the total loss (= weighted sum of all losses) different to parts_loss?

Comment: Are you using regularization?

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thank you!

Comment: Great, I will post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total loss is different from `parts_loss` because it includes the regularization term. In other words, `loss` is computed as `loss = parts_loss + k*R`, where `R` is the regularization term (typically the L1 or L2 norm of the model's weights) and `k` a hyperparameter that controls the contribution of the regularization loss in the total loss.